# Why are the NPC summons for Dragonslayer Armour not appearing?

Tags: dark-souls-3

The two NPC summons that are available for the Dragonslayer Armour are not appearing. The fan site does not mention that any quest must be completed. One is supposed to be in the  Shrine (physical - Sirris), but there are only the main NPCs.

I am Embered when looking for them in the Lothric Castle and it is "The Fire Fades" (GOTY) Edition.

Where are the two NPCs and how to make their summon signs to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two summons available for this fight.

[Eygon of Carin](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Eygon+of+Carim) can be summoned, provided you haven't killed him, or the maiden. His Summon Sign can be found in the building to the right of the stairway leading to the boss fog on the right side just beyond the doorway.

The other Summon Sign belongs to [Sirris](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Sirris+of+the+Sunless+Realms), who, as you mentioned, has a backstory leading up to this event. You will need to have followed her questline up to defeating Creighton the Wanderer, for her sign to appear.

Comment: Ok, but Sirris OG location should be Firelink Shrine if I understand correctly (wiki info), but there are only the main NPCs (Andre, Firekeeper, shrine handmaid,...)Where can I find her?  The trigger should be speaking to Anri&Horace.

Comment: If you haven't spoken to her by this point, you won't be able to start her questline.

Comment: As a note, for Eygon to be available, you cannot let Irina die, get corrupted (by buying a dark miracle from her) or even become a firekeeper (by buying all non-dark miracles from her). I don't think its possible for her to become a firekeeper at that point, but Eygon will become hostile or go away under those conditions. Another note, if you join Rosaria's Fingers convenant, Sirris becomes permantly unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone still reads this, but don't forget you have to be embered to be able to summon. This was the problem in my case.

Comment: The OP mentioned they are embered. And that still doesn't answer the question, though.

Comment: @Joachim Questions and answers on Arqade, and the Stack Exchange network as a whole, are meant to help more than just whoever asked the question. Some other people might have the same issue described in the question even though the details might differ, and it is perfectly okay to address that with other answers.

Comment: @Wrigglenite But this *adds* no new information to the question, it doesn't address anything - this 'advice' can be gleaned by reading the question itself.